# Plot hyperplane Linear SVM python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, svm

I am trying to plot the hyperplane for the model I trained with LinearSVC and sklearn. Note that I am working with natural languages; before fitting the model I extracted features with CountVectorizer and TfidfTransformer.

Here the classifier:

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn import svm

clf = LinearSVC(C=0.2).fit(X_train_tf, y_train)
```

Then I tried to plot as suggested [on the Scikit-learn website](http://scikit-learn.org/0.18/auto_examples/svm/plot_separating_hyperplane.html):

```
# get the separating hyperplane
w = clf.coef_[0]
a = -w[0] / w[1]
xx = np.linspace(-5, 5)
yy = a * xx - (clf.intercept_[0]) / w[1]

# plot the parallels to the separating hyperplane that pass through the
# support vectors
b = clf.support_vectors_[0]
yy_down = a * xx + (b[1] - a * b[0])
b = clf.support_vectors_[-1]
yy_up = a * xx + (b[1] - a * b[0])

# plot the line, the points, and the nearest vectors to the plane
plt.plot(xx, yy, 'k-')
plt.plot(xx, yy_down, 'k--')
plt.plot(xx, yy_up, 'k--')

plt.scatter(clf.support_vectors_[:, 0], clf.support_vectors_[:, 1],
            s=80, facecolors='none')
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=Y, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)

plt.axis('tight')
plt.show()
```

This example uses svm.SVC(kernel='linear'), while my classifier is LinearSVC. Therefore, I get this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-6e231c530d87> in <module>()
      7 # plot the parallels to the separating hyperplane that pass through the
      8 # support vectors
----> 9 b = clf.support_vectors_[0]
     1 yy_down = a * xx + (b[1] - a * b[0])
     11 b = clf.support_vectors_[-1]

AttributeError: 'LinearSVC' object has no attribute 'support_vectors_'
```

How can I successfully plot the hyperplan of my LinearSVC classifier?

Comment: Here it is: http://scikit-learn.org/0.18/auto_examples/svm/plot_separating_hyperplane.html

Comment: I know that in that example they use another kernel for linear SVM, but I would like to plot my classifier

Comment: Well the question reads like you are looking for a the reason of the error, but as the documentation clearly states: *"Note that LinearSVC does not accept keyword kernel, as this is assumed to be linear. It also lacks some of the members of SVC and NuSVC, like `support_`."* I don't know much about the usage of LinearSVC, but I guess you could rephrase the question to make it clear that you want a similar output as `SVC`, but use `LinearSVC` instead, which does not have a `'support_vectors_'` attribute. This way people don't need to dig deep to find the obvious.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about leaving the `support_` out, which is not defined for a `LinearSVC`?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm

np.random.seed(0)
X = np.r_[np.random.randn(20, 2) - [2, 2], np.random.randn(20, 2) + [2, 2]]
Y = [0] * 20 + [1] * 20

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
clf2 = svm.LinearSVC(C=1).fit(X, Y)

# get the separating hyperplane
w = clf2.coef_[0]
a = -w[0] / w[1]
xx = np.linspace(-5, 5)
yy = a * xx - (clf2.intercept_[0]) / w[1]

# create a mesh to plot in
x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
xx2, yy2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, .2),
                     np.arange(y_min, y_max, .2))
Z = clf2.predict(np.c_[xx2.ravel(), yy2.ravel()])

Z = Z.reshape(xx2.shape)
ax.contourf(xx2, yy2, Z, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, alpha=0.3)
ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=Y, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, s=25)
ax.plot(xx,yy)

ax.axis([x_min, x_max,y_min, y_max])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It fails at this line: ----> 8 x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1

Error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

Comment: Yes, I am running the exact code. I use python 3.6, sklearn 0.19, numpy 1.13

Comment: I tried to restart the kernel and now it works. But now how can I plot the hyperplane of the model I have trained?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by hyperplane? Isn't that what's shown in the answer?

Comment: Yes it's exactly that. But in this graph it shows randomly generated points. I want to plot those which my model has classified

Comment: How could I know? I don't know anything about your data. But it should of course work exactly the same way.